# Button in the footer is a different size on different page lengths

Tags: html, css

I am creating a footer used in a layout on every page. The footer has two div tags that look like buttons. The problem i am running into is the button are smaller on some screens and larger on others. It looks like if the content of the page does not take the full height of the screen, the footer buttons are the correct size. If the content of the page is over the full height of the screen the buttons are smaller. I believe they should stay the same height.

**Here is some screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

```css
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #444444;
}

.footer-left {
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer-item {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.footer-button {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.footer-help-center {
  background-color: #0B5C8E;
  border: 2px solid #0B5C8E;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-list">
      <li class="footer-left">
        <img src="~/content/images/logo-icon.png">
      </li>
      <li class="footer-item">
        <div class="footer-button footer-help-center">Help Center</div>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-item">
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(" ContactUs ")">
          <div class="footer-button footer-contact-us">Contact Us</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Relative length units specify a length relative to another length property. Relative length units scales better between different rendering mediums.
>
> **rem**: Relative to font-size of the root element

[CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

From this I can say when you are using rem which could be depended on root element font size or browser font size. That will make your website renders bit different between browsers.

Comment: This will not make your site render different. It can make it different if you explicitly changed the browser size. All browsers come with 16px as default.

Comment: yeah, I forgot the default 16px size. But it could be the one if the browser size is not default, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure it can, sounded like the answer hinted on that this was the cause. Maybe I just missred the intent?

Comment: this was the issue. I change the font-size to 14px and the footer renders correctly in size across all page heights.
```
.footer-button {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one you are missing the element `<ul>` wrapping your `<li>`. After that I would suggest to clean up elements that don't need to be there, take a look at my example. Like you don't need to have a div inside the `<a>` element.

```css
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #444444;
}

.footer-left {
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer-item {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.footer-button {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.footer-help-center {
  background-color: #0B5C8E;
  border: 2px solid #0B5C8E;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
}

.footer-contact-us {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  border: 2px solid #0B5C8E;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">

    <ul class="footer-list">
      <li class="footer-left">
        <img src="~/content/images/logo-icon.png">
      </li>
      <li class="footer-item">
        <a class="footer-button footer-help-center">Help Center</a>
      </li>
      <li class="footer-item">
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl(" ContactUs ")" class="footer-button footer-contact-us">
          Contact Us
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around a bit but can't seem to replicate exactly what you are seeing other than the text wrapping when the window gets narrow. The css for footer-contact-us is missing but I assume it's about the same as footer-help-center.

If you want the buttons to always be the same height, why not just tell them to be?

```css
.footer-button {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .footer {
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .footer-container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    
    .footer-list {
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 15px;
      color: #444444;
    }
    
    .footer-left {
      margin-right: auto;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .footer-item {
      margin-right: 1rem;
    }
    
    .footer-button {
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 0.9rem;
      margin: 2px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .footer-help-center.success {
      background-color: #0B5C8E;
      border: 2px solid #0B5C8E;
      color: white !important;
      padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
      font-size: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .footer-contact-us.info {
      background-color: #33691e;
      border: 2px solid #33691e;
      color: white !important;
      padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
      font-size: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">
      <div class="footer-list">
        <li class="footer-left">
          <img src="~/content/images/logo-icon.png">
        </li>
        <li class="footer-item">
          <a class="btn success footer-button footer-help-center">Help Center</a>
        </li>
        <li class="footer-item">
          <a class="btn info footer-button footer-contact-us" href="@Url.RouteUrl(" ContactUs ")">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```